# What ports does freeswitch need open?

Tags: freeswitch

I have installed FreeSWITCH 1.0.6 on CentOS 5.5.  I believe CentOS is blocking the ports FreeSWITCH needs in order to contact with my remote phones, but I have no idea how to use ipTables in Linux or what ports need to be open.  Can anyone help?

With Asterisk the ports were 5060 - 5090 for sip and a few others but I don't remember them.

Thank you!

Comment: I just called my web host - they told me that by default the VPS image  blocks all traffic except for SSH & port 80.  Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Nevermind chumps, I figured it out myself:

```
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8021 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5080 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 8021 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m udp -p udp --dport 5080 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5532 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5564 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is a bad answer... FreeSWITCH does not use all these ports, and not all port are defined there. For those needing a guideline (using default configs):

```
3478 - STUN Discovery (UDP)
3479 - STUN Discovery (UDP)
5060 - Sofia Internal Profile (TCP & UDP)
5080 - Sofia External Profile (TCP & UDP)
8021 - Event Socket (TCP)
16384-32768 - RTP Ports (UDP)
```

Port usage is subject to change with module usage. You can find the entry on http://confluence.freeswitch.org, and more (up to date) information about port usage can be found at https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Firewall

Answer (score 1):

Best reference seems to be :
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Firewall

All of the ports are dependent on your module usage (ie. 8080 if you are using the [web api](http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Webapi)). Keep in mind that all of the ports mentioned are defaults and are configurable.

Answer (score 1):

I could not match FreeSWITCH wiki to ports to my setup, in the end I went with what actual open ports were reported by my machine, run the following to find out what FreeSWITCH is using on your rig:

```
root@tardis:~# netstat -lntp | grep freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:2856          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:5066          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:7443          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:5080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:5060          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 192.0.1.2:2855          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8081                :::*                    LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8082                :::*                    LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 :::8021                 :::*                    LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5080                :::*                    LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5060                :::*                    LISTEN      7220/freeswitch
```